# DatGui & Three.js not cooperating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, dat.gui

My desire is to implement the 'Dat.gui' library for my 'Three.js' project using React Hooks.

**When implementing with es6** 
I get the desired look i want, but i struggle to send and update values due to not having any statehandling.

```
import React from 'react'
import * as dat from 'dat.gui';

var FizzyText = function() {
    this.message = 'dat.gui';
    this.speed = 0.8;
    this.displayOutline = false;
  };

    var text = new FizzyText();
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(text, 'message');
    gui.add(text, 'speed', -5, 5);
    gui.add(text, 'displayOutline');

export default function GUIHandler() {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

**The desired look using the code above**
[image]

**The React implementation(using react class component)**

```
import React from 'react';
import DatGui, { DatBoolean, DatColor, DatNumber, DatString } from 'react-dat-gui';

export default class GUIHandler extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      package: 'react-dat-gui',
      power: 9000,
      isAwesome: true,
      feelsLike: '#2FA1D6',
    }
  }

  // Update current state with changes from controls
  handleUpdate = newData =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: { ...prevState.data, ...newData }
    }));

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return (
      <DatGui data={data} onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}>
        <DatString path='package' label='Package' />
        <DatNumber path='power' label='Power' min={9000} max={9999} step={1} />
        <DatBoolean path='isAwesome' label='Awesome?' />
        <DatColor path='feelsLike' label='Feels Like' />
      </DatGui>
    )
  }
}
```

**The React code look** unfortunatley it gets stuck outside the canvas and just looks bad
[image: Undesired look]

Any recommendations on how i can get this to work (preferably with React hooks) would be much appreciated.

Comment: The react version could probably be fixed with some CSS tweaks. Is your canvas using `position: absolute;`?

Comment: The Canvas doesnt have any css implementation at all.

Comment: Well, there you go! Dat.GUI is taking up space in the DOM and the canvas is being pushed down. Add a little CSS to position your elements, and you should be good to go!

Comment: There is an open issue on the repo https://github.com/claus/react-dat-gui/issues/43 for now you can imoprt the style sheet.